# create temp files in tomcat webapps folder

Tags: gwt, tomcat, web-applications, war

I have a Google Web Project which works perfect on Development mode. Somewhere inside this project, I create some .xml files which I delete after parsing.

When I deploy the .war file of my project in Tomcat7 (var/lib/tomcat7/webapps) (I use the tomcat manage to deploy it) the project fails to create any file. I've tried all possible paths inside the webapps folder. I even tried context.getRealPath("/")+"/ROOT/tmp/" but nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the temp folder instead of attempting to write directly to your webapp's deployment directory:

```
ServletContext app = (servlet).getServletContext();
File tmpDir = (File)app.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
File targetFile = new File(tmpDir, "mytempfile.xml");
...
```

Remember to do everything in a try/catch block and properly clean-up your resources in the 'finally' block or you'll be sorry ;)

Comment: Actually I managed to do it my way playing with the path. The thing is that I want to write my files in a publicly available folder. So even ROOT won't help...

Comment: So, you need to write temporary files to a publicly-available folder? Why? If you are using ServletContext.getRealPath() then you are writing a broken application.

Comment: Well, I need to write KML files in a publicly available folder, so that I can present them on a gmap. It is not possible to parse local KML files so I try to find a trick to manage it

Comment: @mariosk89 I see. Just be aware that there are a number of surprising things that happen when files are created within a deployed webapp's directory structure. You've been warned.

Comment: thnx!!! Currenlty, I use JSNI and parse my kml as strings using geoxml3, which is a Javascript library. I'm just trying to find a better and quicker way to do it

Comment: You could also generate the XML documents on the fly in direct response to a request... is there an advantage to caching these things? If they are small, you could even cache them to memory and serve them directly from there: no disk = faster response time.