# Path for creating a file in Tomcat

Tags: java, xml, file, tomcat, path

I created a website setting file in the xml format, and the content of this file specifies things like website title, url, meta description, admin email, etc.

In my Java code, I simply defined the file as following:

```
private static final String webSettingFileName = "WebSettings.xml";

public void saveSetting()
{
    File settingFile = new File(webSettingFileName);
    // try-catch block to write the XML file omitted
}
```

After I deploy the war file, I found out that the web Setting xml file was written to the Tomcat bin folder, however, I would like to write the file inside the ROOT folder of webapps in Tomcat. So I am wondering how to specify the file path in my code. Thanks

**Edit:**

As Jarrod Roberson gave me a red -1 for duplicate question. I disagree with him, because I had checked the post before making this post. I tried the method suggested in [that post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802242/create-temp-files-in-tomcat-webapps-folder), but it does not work for me, because I need to save the web settings file persistently in the same location no matter how many times Tomcat has restarted (so tomcat/webapps serves my purpose!). The file is for saving website settings. In addition, the ServletContext don't seem working in Java 1.8 that I am using for my webapp.

**Edit 2:**

This is how I finally made it work:

```
private final static File catalinaBase = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base")).getAbsoluteFile();
private static final String webSettingFileName = "WebSetting.xml"; 
private final static File file = new File(catalinaBase, "webapps/" + webSettingFileName);
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying it an absolute path?

Comment: Neither one is a good idea.  You ought to have that in a WAR file for your application, not the Tomcat ROOT.

Comment: yes, writing the file in the WAR file is a better idea, but not sure how to do it. Should I place something like {Context}/webSettingFileName in the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `ServletContext.getRealPath("/")` to retrieve the absolute filesystem path of the current webapp, e.g.:

```
File settingFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), webSettingFileName);
```

Note that this will only work with an exploded (unzipped) war file.